# Configure cloud run instances to accept internet requests but only from specified cidr range

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to configure specific cloud run instances (which are all part of my VPC) to only allow ingress traffic from a specific source (e.g. my companies IP address).

It seems that if I have the "Ingress" setting, set to "All" (which allows access from the internet), my firewall rules have no effect.

I found a setting "Route all traffice through VPC" which I thought would sort it, as it meant internet traffic would then be routed through and my firewall rules applied, but no dice.

I'd rather not have to configure my APIs source code to whitelist ips, I can't seem to find any guides which cover this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You will find few guides because it's not the correct way to design and use serverless services. It's better to base your access on the identity (Zero Trust design) than on the network (Network based security). Even Google says "don't trust the network".

---

Anyway, you can still achieve what you want, but it's not straight forward!

firstly, you need to add a [HTTPS Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) in front of your Cloud Run service. For that, you can use [serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) to reference your Cloud Run service.

Be sure that your Load Balancer route the traffic to Cloud Run before continuing (it could take up to 10 minutes to advertise the configuration to the Google infrastructure).

Then, you can activate [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor) on your load balancer and create a policy that allows [only a range of IP](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#types_of_rules)

test again.

Finally to be sure that Cloud Run is not accessible directly from the internet, [update the ingress and set it to "internal and cloud load balancing".](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress)

Comment: I'd like to follow best practices, so in the case of access to a company portal, I only want people connected to our VPN to actually see a login page, by identity I'm assuming you mean a configuration of 1/more gcp identity, can you give any more details on that?

Comment: Yes, Identity is a user logged with its Google Account (Gmail, Google Workspance,...). Do your corp user have a Google Account? If so, why the VPN requirement?

Comment: Well, the VPN was (previous to this conversation) my current idea to ensure only known users to our company would have any access at all.

Ok do you mean logged into a google account at the browser level? As that would be pretty sweet actually

Comment: Ah hang on, you're talking about logging in with a google identity right? Rather than the accounts we currently have

Comment: Still a bit concerning that the firewall rules seem to have no effect on the cloud run instance though, what's the point of them?

Comment: Firewall affect only Compute Engine. Not serverless product. Anyway, forget the VPN, I recommend you to use IAP and Cloud Run. You still need a HTTPS Load Balancer, but you can grant a domain (for instance: @mycompany.com) and only the user of your company (logged with the Google Account in mycompany.com) will be authorized to see the login page. The others will have a "forbidden" page. And for this filtering, you pay nothing, only the load balancer!! https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run